# My IMEI was deleted, but I wrote down the number. Can I restore it?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, imei

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I restore IMEI code after factory reset?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19094/how-can-i-restore-imei-code-after-factory-reset)

I have an SGS2.  During an OTA update the IMEI was deleted.  I didn't have a backup of the EFS directory, as the phone wasn't rooted.  However, I copied down the IMEI on paper beforehand.

Is there any way to restore the IMEI if I have the number?

Comment: Start here with this [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/27396/18822) to an exact duplicate of your question.

Comment: @zero2cx you should flag it as duplicate :)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, because these things are very phone-specific.

Comment: It's specific to Samsung Phones because they store the IMEI in the /efs/ folder

Answer (score 1):

*I've a Samsung Galaxy S1, but it will probably also work for you...*

What I did, I flashed a Stock ROM via ODIN with Re-Partition enabled. (Don't know if it's necesseary) The stock ROM automatically regenerated my EFS-Folder and my IMEI... (See the Thread [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28963/how-to-restore-my-imei))

This worked for me, but [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1264021) might also help you.

I don't know any way to restore your IMEI, just because you know it. (It's written behind your battery anyways) The EFS-Folder which stores the IMEI is encrypted.