# Invalid IMEI on HTC One X after factory reset

Tags: htc-one-x, imei

I performed a factory reset on my phone, and now it says that I have an invalid IMEI. I cannot call anyone or get calls.

Phone model: HTC One X
Android Version: 4.1.5
Baseband Version: 201206010808
Kernel Version: 4.1.5
Build Number: ONE X 4.1.5 HTC
Build version: 4.1.5

Comment: How did that happen? A factory reset just wipes the `/data` and `/cache` partition, something is missing from this... just saying... were you messing with something there that is omitted from the question?

Comment: Related: [How to fix “Invalid IMEI ” after Factory reset?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/8570/16575), [How can I restore IMEI code after factory reset?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/19094/16575), [How to restore my IMEI?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28963/16575)