# How to restore IMEI and get back network functionality?

Tags: cyanogenmod, system-error

Related, but no solution: [How to restore my IMEI on Galaxy S if I don't have a backup of /efs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28963/how-to-restore-my-imei-on-galaxy-s-if-i-dont-have-a-backup-of-efs)

My IMEI has turned blank after a nightly update, I can see it is blank when typing *#06# and I have no GSM functionality. Also baseband version is unknown.

I do have a backup of the /efs directory. I have restored the contents. But even before restoring, I checked the md5sum of the mps_code.dat file, and it was the same as the backup, so I didn't have my hopes up.

Nevertheless, I did a full overwrite of the contents with my backup. Rebooted, no change.

I have also tried to do a factory reset, reinstall Cyanogenmod, two different versions, wiped cache, Dalvik. Remove the battery, SIM card, USB cable.

I am willing to install the stock firmware, if I could find it, or patch the modem firmware somehow. Where should I go from here in a situation such as this one?

Answer (score 1):

If you also have "No Baseband" in the about screen, You can try to flash only the modem and see if it help.

e.g With Samsung devices, I usually use Odin with the ROM from SamMobile, 
I extract the modem file from the archive and put into a new `.tar` file, and then flash the new file with Odin.

On Linux i can use Heimdall which allow my to directly flash a specific region like the modem.